# How do I get movie IDs from an url having numbers and words?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to extract all the movie IDs from the movie_link variables.

```r
movie_webpage <- read_html("http://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_wl_img_3")
movie_nodes <- html_nodes(movie_webpage,'.titleColumn a')
movie_link = sapply(html_attrs(movie_nodes),`[[`,'href')
movieid <- movie_webpage %>%
  html_node(".titleColumn a") %>%
  html_attr("href")
```

"/title/tt0111161/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&pf_rd_r=EE9DQ2NA8KK0XDG1CS8Q&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_1"

The result should be: `tt0111161`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same movie-id is stored at multiple places one of them is ribbon at the end of each movie, you could get the movie-id from `data-tconst` attribute without getting involved into much complication.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "http://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_wl_img_3"

url %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes("div.wlb_ribbon") %>%
  html_attr("data-tconst")

#[1] "tt0111161" "tt0068646" "tt0071562" "tt0468569" "tt0050083" "tt0108052"
#[7] "tt0167260" "tt0110912" "tt0060196" "tt0137523" "tt0120737" "tt0109830"
#....
```